# Is it possible to circumvent this overflow?

Tags: numerics, special-functions

I'm trying to evaluate the following function numerically:

$
f(A,B)=\frac{2A\pi ^{5/2} (-1)^B}{(A!)^2B!} \,
   _4\tilde{F}_3\left({\frac{1}{2},1-A,1-A,1-B\atop \frac{1}{2}-A,\frac{1}{2}-A,\frac{1}{2}-B}\bigg|
   1\right)
$

By construction, $0\leq f(A,B)\leq 1$ as long as A and B are positive integers. My problem is that the values of A and B that I need are quite large powers of 2 (in the ballpark of $2^{100}$, possibly larger and not too different, like  $A=2^{103},\ B=2^{97}$). The problem is that the regularized Hypergeometric function returns very large values and the computation eventually overflows/undeflows already at $2^{50}$ on my system.

Of course, on paper these large values of the numerator are taken care of by the factorials in the denominator, but Mathematica seems to deal with the numerator and the denominator independently, which is what causes the overflow.

Is anyone aware of a trick that I can use? At the moment the best I can do is to feed approximated values to the function (e.g. `2.^40.` rather than `2^40`), but while this speeds up the evaluation it does not stop the overflow/undeflow.
I could use Stirling's approximation of the denominator, but I don't know what to do with the numerator.

EDIT: for completeness, this is the code I'm using, with memoization (The `Re` is to avoid small spurious imaginary components creeping up in the numerical evaluation):

```
f[A_, B_] :=  f[A, B] = 
Re[(2 A (-1)^B Pi^2.5
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 1 - A, 1 - A, 1 - B},
{1/2 - A, 1/2 - A, 1/2 - B}, 1])/(B! (A!)^2)]
```

Comment: Including *Mathematica* code will often help you get an answer sooner or better.

Comment: Yes you are right, although the code in this case is simply the MMA version of the definition. But I will add it now.

Comment: With what runtimes are you dealing with? I am running your code on $A=2^{103}$ and $B=2^{97}$ since approximately 30min now with no result (or error) yet.

Comment: this may be more of a http://math.stackexchange.com question.

Comment: @Jinxed, may as well abort, it will certainly overflow just because of the factorials.

Comment: @george2079: The question is: After what time. I really like to reproduce the behavior, if feasible.

Comment: @Jinxed I am very surprised. I am not bothered by a long computation time, I just get overflows (I'm on Mac OS X). Oh, for $A=2^{43}$ and $B=2^{37}$ I now get "MemoryAllocationFailure" errors...

Comment: I am running your exact code now (again, since I just quit all my kernels - just in case...). Runs with very moderate memory requirements ($\approx\ 55\:\text{MB}$) since 3mins. Hold on: Not your exact code! I left out the `f[A,B]=` part, since I did not see any use for it.

Comment: fyi the result of `f[2^(n+6),2^n]` appears to be nearly constant.  The largest I can get to eval in a reasonable time is  `f[2^20, 2^14] // N -> 0.996094`

Comment: Hm.. anyways, I will also try what @george2079 suggested. There might be a clever mathematical trick that I can use.

Comment: Running a second kernel with the `f[A,B]=` part in parallel now. Same behavior as the first one: $<55\ \text{MB}$, and running for some minutes now without any problem.

Comment: 15mins now: No problems yet.

Comment: I stopped the trial after 75mins now: No obvious change in memory consumption, no errors, just continuous evaluation. 10.0.2 on Win 8.1 x64 here.

Comment: Okay, thank you for doing this test!